# Как добавить картинку к url

Tags: html, url

Я новичок в программировании. Как сделать, чтобы при отправке ссылки где либо появлялась рядом с ней какая то фотография. Нужен ли для этого тег. Если это нельзя сделать, то скажите. Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. «Где либо» это где, «рядом с ней» это где? И при чём тут программирование?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как сделать, чтобы при **отправке** ссылки где либо появлялась рядом с ней какая то фотография

это зависит от того самого "где либо"

если по e-mail отправляете то нужны html теги(`<img src='my_photo.jpeg'>`)

если на форуме каком нибудь, то в большинстве случаев нужны BBcode \ MarkDown или их аналоги.

но во многих современных дэсктопных ресурсах(web), возиться со всем этим нет нужды. достаточно "драг эн дропнуть" нужную фотку с рабочего стола прямо в текстовое поле.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос.
Если вы имеете ввиду как использовать url картинки чтобы поместить на свою страницу, то вам поможет свойство в CSS:

```
background-image: url(ссылка на изображение);
```

в случае если вы хотите сделать это только через html, тогда воспользуйтесь:

```
<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст">
```